# How to replace Fragment with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to load a FragmentActivity from another FragmentActivity (instead of a Fragment), but am getting an error. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void displayView(int position) {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Tab_Day.TAG) == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, fragmentAct, Tab_Day.TAG).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
The method replace(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentActivity, String)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FragmentActivity` is not a subclass of `Fragment` it is a subclass of `Activity`. If you are trying to start a new activity then you use `startActivity(Intent intent)` otherwise fragmentAct should be a `Fragment`.

They are not interchangeable. A `FragmentActivity` hosts `Fragment`s.

Comment: Is there a way to put a FragmentedTabHost in a fragment then (instead of a FragmentActivity)?